# 18.04 - Can't Get 64 bit Ubuntu on my Intel Core i7-6500u to start in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: xubuntu, 64-bit, intel

try to start and get Kernel requires x86-64 CPU, but only detects i686

Comment: Do you have virtualization extensions enabled in your BIOS?  If you do not, it may need to be turned on (Intel Virtualization Extensions).

Comment: I will have to fine out to BIOS … let me look that up (unless you have a refer)

Comment: You're welcome.  I rewrote my comment as an answer.  Feel free to mark it as accepted to indicate this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable virtualization extensions in your BIOS.

By default, this is typically turned off in the BIOS; to virtualize a 64bit CPU you have to enable the virtualization extensions in your BIOS/UEFI firmware.